# Trivial 'Bootstrap Table' (pasted from docs) not sortable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable, bootstrap-table

See rendered page at http://pub.admc.com/tmp/trivial.html.
You can see that I'm getting jQuery, Bootstrap, and Bootstrap from CDN, each as instructed in the corresponding product documentation.

It seems that all 3 products are loading successfully.  If I change to load table data from JSON, then the JSON populates the table skeleton successfully, but it's still not sortable.  Chrome JavaScript console runs 100% clean.

According to the [doc reference table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) (only kind of docs there are for Bootstrap Table :( ), bootstrap-tablified tables should be sortable by default.  Nevertheless I added attribute data-sortable=true but that has no effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap Table samples</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item ID</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>$1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that though the table element defaults to `data-sortable=true`, nothing can be sorted by default since all columns default to `sortable=false`.

With everything else in default state, you enable sorting column-by-column by adding attr `data-sortable=true` to `th` elements.